# How to clear "warning: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

When I compile a program with GCC, it will show that *"warning: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]"*.

The code in question is the following:

```c
typedef int BOOL;
```

How can I clear the warning?

Comment: What command do you use to compile? What header files have you included?

Comment: It's a huge program which I download from the net.So I can't explain it clearly.I thought it was a general question.If not,sorry.

Comment: `BOOL` is probably already defined as a macro.

Comment: perhaps BOOL is declared as a macro such as **unsigned** or **short**, therefore your code now stands `typedef int short` which aliases nothing at all as a short int. Who knows.

Comment: What version of gcc was this?  No version I tried accepts `-fpermissive` in C mode (nor mentions it in any warning message). Maybe you actually invoked the compiler in C++ mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following. Similar worked for me with a union that was catching a warning.

```
typedef int BOOL;
...

BOOL unused;
(void)unused;
```

The `(void)unused;` avoids the subsequent unused variable warning. Its portable across all compilers.